# Display all chars in a text box after iterating through an input c#

Tags: c#, foreach, ascii

I am just starting out learning C# at college.

Below is my simple code to convert each char from a text box input to an int, in order to get its ascii value. Then display it in a text box. My problem is that, for example, if I enter 'abc' into TextBox1, TextBox2 only displays 99, which is the value for the last char entered. How can I modify this to display all of the input into TextBox2?

```
        string output = textBox1.Text;

        foreach (char c in output)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(c);

            string r = Convert.ToString(i);


            textBox2.Text = r;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `textBox2.Text = r;` to `textBox2.Text += r;`

This will append to the text instead of replacing it for each character.

Comment: Thanks this Worked!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly textBox2 text field must be cleared. After than you append value in a loop

```
string output = textBox1.Text;


textBox2.Text = string.Empty;

foreach (char c in output)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(c);

    string r = Convert.ToString(i);

    // modify this line
    textBox2.Text += r;
}
```

Or shortest version is that

```
 textBox2.Text = string.Join(string.Empty,textBox1.Text.ToList().ConvertAll(Convert.ToInt32));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the value of the string r each loop, you need to update it. 
Not sure if you want a space or some other seperator between numbers?

```
string output = textBox1.Text;
string r = "";
        foreach (char c in output)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            // this takes what is in r and appends the new value into the string r.  If you need a space or something you can add that in each loop like I did below, or remove that if you do not need a seperator
            r += Convert.ToString(i) + " ";



        }
textBox2.Text = r;
```

Comment: Thanks, I want it to convert even the spaces to its ascii value as it will become part of a cipher program.

Comment: Ok, then just dont add the extra space.  I did that for an example, you can just remove that.